# How to fix the error when using gitstats with git in windows

Tags: windows, git

I'm learning how to use gitstats to create reports with git. So I downloaded and installed Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe , python-2.6.2.msi , gp463-win32-setup.exe(gnuplot) and cloned gitstats

from http://gitstats.com/. And I also add my git, python, gnuplot, gitstats to my PATH. Then I created a repository with "Git Bash" by myself named repo1. But when I input the command to create the

reporting about repo1, it output an error like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Dynamsoft220\Desktop>e:
E:\>cd Jeremy\Git\gitstats
E:\Jeremy\Git\gitstats>python gitstats e:\Jeremy\Git\repo1 e:\Jeremy\Git\report
[0.08100] >> gnuplot --version
Output path: e:\Jeremy\Git\report
Git path: e:\Jeremy\Git\repo1
Collecting data...
[0.12600] >> git shortlog -s HEAD | wc -l
[0.08300] >> git show-ref --tags
[0.18100] >> git rev-list --pretty=format:"%at %ai %aN <%aE>" HEAD | grep -v ^co
mmit
[0.09300] >> git rev-list --pretty=format:"%at %T" HEAD | grep -v ^commit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 341, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 450, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named gitstats
```

I really have no idea about how to fix this error. Actually I thought maybe it is because the software version is too late, but it seems not! It seems too simple to be discussed for most of people

TT, so I can't find a lot of article about it. Any suggestions will be appreciate! Thanks~

Answer (score 11):

I was also having problems getting gitstats to run on Windows. This was tricky, because it **looks** like everything is working, but it just doesn't work!

Here are a few tweaks that helped me.
First, I made sure PYTHON_PATH was set correctly and added it to the path:

```powershell
C:\> set PYTHON_PATH=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;%PYTHON_PATH%
```

Next, I added gitstats to the path, because, well, why not at this point:

```
C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\projects\gitstats
```

Last, rename* `gitstats` to `gitstats.py`:

```
C:\> cd projects\gitstats
C:\> ren gitstats gitstats.py
```

<sub>* The rename was mentioned in the issue log on github, and solved by @danio there: https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats/issues/34</sub>

Comment: Prefect. Still relevant. Thanks

Comment: Emphasis on renaming the python file to a .py extension

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `gitstat` folder in the PYTHON_PATH.

See this answer for how to add the PYTHON_PATH in windows.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3701730/1226582

Comment: What is "the gitstat folder"? The folder containing the source?

Comment: It's the folder where the actual gitstats sourcecode is, not the project's source.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought :/. I ended up using https://github.com/trybeee/GitStats which I managed to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more complete instructions for running [gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/) in Windows:

- Install Python2 from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/ (it might be a good idea to *not* add it to your PATH to avoid messing up your other Python installation)
- Install gnuplot from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/latest/download (you can add it to path)

Now run **in git bash**:

If you haven't downloaded it yet: "install" gitstats

- `git clone git://github.com/hoxu/gitstats.git`
- `cd gitstats`

Now every time you want to run it, first add Python 2 to (the front of) your PATH temporarily so gitstats can use it:

- `PYTHON_PATH=/C/Python27:/C/Python27/Lib:/C/Python27/DLLs:/C/Python27/Lib/lib-tk`
- `PATH=$PYTHON_PATH:$PATH:"/C/Program Files/gnuplot/bin"`
- `python gitstats /C/path/to/repo/to/analyze /C/path/to/output/dir`
- Now open `C:\path\to\output\dir\index.html` in your browser